# Диалог выбора картинки

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, как реализовать диалог выбора картинки для дальнейшего её загрузки на сервер?
В качестве библиотеки для сетевого взаимодействия использую okhttp

Comment: вам что нужно? - помощь в создании диалога? или как отправлять картинки на сервер? поконкретнее

Answer (score 2):

Объявляете метод:

```
private void pickImage() {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY_FILES);
}
```

По желанию, объявляете еще один метод (который возвращает полный путь по `Uri`):

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

Далее переопределяете `onActivityResult(...)`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent returnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, returnedIntent);
    if (returnedIntent == null) 
        return;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY_FILES:
            Uri uri = returnedIntent.getData();
            String path = getRealPathFromURI(uri);
            break;
    }
}
```

В итоге, в `path` получаете путь к картинке.